# PHPMyAdmin errors on main page

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

я пытался установить Apache2.4 + PHP + MySQL + PHPMyAdmin. У меня получилось всё, кроме одной проблемы с PHPMyAdmin. PHPMyAdmin выдаёт много ошибок. Я прикреплю скриншоты. Я знаю достаточно мало про MySQL, поэтому решение может быть очень простым и глупым. На первом скриншоте ошибка с главной страницы, на втором ошибка, появляющаяся при переходе на вкладку Databases(Базы данных), вкладки SQL и Status(Состояние) работают нормально, на третьем скриншоте ошибка, выпадающая при переходе на влкадку User accounts(Пользователи), на четвёртом скриншоте ошибка при переходе на вкладку Charsets и пятый скриншот - таблица 'user', в которой присутствует пользователь 'mysql.infoschema' на хосте 'localhost'. Остальные вкладки работают нормально.
Я использовал Apache 2.4.37, PHP 7.2.12, MySQL 8.0.13 и PHPMyAdmin 4.8.3, всё стоит на Windows 10 Professional. Помогите, пожалуйста, я пытаюсь начать учить PHP и MySQL, но эта ошибка мешает мне.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: welcome to ruSO Nikita, please, follow the rules and ask in russian

Comment: ну раз шпрехает https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в вопросе, который привёл Jean-Claude речь идёт о исчезновении пользователя, который являлся дефайнером, при переносе таблиц с одного сервера на другой. У меня же таблиц нету, только стандартная БД 'mysql' с таблицами 'user' и другими. Таблицы/БД я не переносил, это созданный впервые сервер. Пользователь, как я сказал в посте, существует. Также, простите, что на английском, я думал это обычный стак.